# ERB is not outputting DIV Tag class as expected in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a div with class defined as follows in my view

```
<div class=<%= "validation-#{index} questions col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1" %>>
```

But String interpolation is not working well in the view I am getting output as

```
<div class="validation-1" questions="" col-lg-8="" col-lg-offset-2="" col-md-9="" col-md-offset-1="" col-sm-9="" col-sm-offset-1="" col-xs-11="" col-xs-offset-1="">
```

Can anybody please tell the mistake?

Comment: Could you provide us example of expected output to see what you would like it to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div class=<%= "validation-#{index} questions col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1" %>>
```

to this:

```
<div class='<%= "validation-#{index} questions col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1" %>'>
```

While it'd be much cleaner and less confusing if you change code to this:

```
<div class='questions col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 <%= "validation-#{index}" %>'>
```

Issue is that your ERB code is evaluated and rendered to HTML as `<div class= validation-1 questions col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 >` but since browser is smart enough to correct the mistake it takes the first string and assign it to class: `class= "validation-1 "` and rest would be converted as property and value(which is "") next after the another.

Comment: I am glad that your issue is solved. Please accept it as answer if answer helped you. :)